# What event will be raised if I close a form opened using ShowDialog method?

Tags: c#, winforms

What event will be raised if I close a form opened using `ShowDialog` method?

Comment: Probably : GotFocus ?

Comment: Do you need to listen for an event?  Can't you just detect it by the fact that your code after the call to `ShowDialog` will start running?

Comment: Thank @JamesThorpe.Yes, I need to listent for an event raise in fParent when fPopup closes. I tried with Enter, Activate events, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you read my second sentence?  This really does strike me as an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where "listening for an event" is the wrong solution.

Comment: Thank @James Thorpe, now i know that my test function is must located at fPopup_Closed event, not at fParent_Activated event in this case.

Comment: And thank @x for your time!

Answer (score 0):

`ShowDialog` makes your code awaits until the user closes the "Dialog" form that you showed.

```
fPopup.ShowDialog(fParent)
Console.WriteLine("I'm here");
```

`"I'm here"` is executed once the user closes the Dialog form, you i can't really see why you need an event when you can just execute anything you want after the `ShowDialog` call and get the same result.

Comment: Thank @user3185569, now i know that my test function is must located at fPopup_Closed event, not at fParent_Activated event in this case.

Answer (score 0):

First is `FormClosing` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.110).aspx)

Second is `FormClosed` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank @Andrew so much, now i know that my test function is must located at fPopup_Closed event, not at fParent_Activated event in this case